# Config transformations and “TransformXml task failed” error message

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, configuration, visual-studio-2010, publishing

I’ve just enabled config transformations on a .NET 3.5 project in VS2010 RC after watching Scott Hanselman’s [video on web deployment](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WebDeploymentMadeAwesomeIfYoureUsingXCopyYoureDoingItWrong.aspx). Unfortunately every time I go to publish I now get the following error:

> The "TransformXml" task failed
>   unexpectedly.
>   System.UriFormatException: Invalid
>   URI: The URI is empty.    at
>   System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri,
>   Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
>   at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString) 
>   at
>   Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.TransformXml.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost
>   taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext
>   taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost,
>   ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode
>   howToExecuteTask, Boolean& taskResult)

If I take a brand new VS2010 web application which already has the config transformations by default I don’t have a problem so I suspect my issue is project related. Has anyone come across this before or have any ideas on a fix?

Comment: awesome video, thanks for the link

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Looks like the answer was simple yet obscure; I had an app setting (a password), which contained a ">" symbol. I tried converting the app to .NET 4 then back to .NET 3.5 and everything ran fine as during the process the symbol had been escaped to ">". Never had a problem with this character until config transformations came along but at least the fix is now simple.

Edit: blogged about in a bit more detail: [Visual Studio 2010 Config Transformations TransformXml task failure](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/03/visual-studio-2010-config.html)

Comment: Same issue here with a .NET 3.5 WCF service.  Your solution worked a treat.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: my project was already targeting .NET 4.0, so I switched it to 3.5 and then back to 4.0 and it works that way as well.